# If statement error in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, if-statement

I am doing a product page and I want "You maybe need also these products".

For example if `productID` is 2 then show me link to `productID` 5.

I have tried to do it with this:

```
<% if(Item.ProductID == 2) { %>
    <a href="ProductDetails.aspx?productID=5">
        <img src="/Catalog/Images/suihkukaappi.png"
            width="100" height="75" style="border: solid" /></a>
<% } %>
```

But it gives me the error "The name 'Item' does not exist in current context." And link works fine if I take this `if` statement off but the same link is every product page.

Here is my code inside `ItemTemplate` from aspx page:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div>
        <h1><%#:Item.ProductName %></h1>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="/Catalog/Images<%#:Item.ImagePath %>" style="border:solid; height:150px; width:175px;" alt="<%#:Item.ProductName %>"/>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>  
            <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align:left;">
                <b>Tuoteselostus:</b><br /><%#:Item.Description %>
                <br />
                <span><b>Hinta:</b>&nbsp;<%#: String.Format("{0:c}", Item.UnitPrice) %></span>
                <br />
                <span><b>Tuotenumero:</b>&nbsp;<%#:Item.ProductID %></span>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <% if(Item.ProductID == 2) { %>
                    <a href="ProductDetails.aspx?productID=5">
                        <img src="/Catalog/Images/suihkukaappi.png"
                            width="100" height="75" style="border: solid" />
                    </a>
                <% } %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You can set the `Visible` property along with `runat=server` for anchor with your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Container.DataItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.idataitemcontainer.dataitem(v=vs.110).aspx) and cast it to the corresponding model that you are iterating over:

```
<% if(((Product)Container.DataItem).ProductID == 2) { %>
```

Comment: I tried that, but says from Product that "Type or namespace name 'Product' could not be found (are you missing a using directive assembly reference?). Visual studio give me option to change that '(KodinPutki.Models.Product).Container...'

 And name 'Container' does not exist in current context. I can't really know what's problem.